# How to access values of a table column of a table declared in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

My stored procedure is:

```
alter PROCEDURE uspApprovalHistory
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
            @empID int = null
AS
BEGIN
    declare @SRFTable table
    (SRFID nvarchar(50))
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into @SRFTable
    Select MasterCode from CallForwarding 
    Where EmployeeNo = @empID or ApproverNo = @empID;

    Select * From callforwarding Where @SRFID[i] = Mastercode

END
GO
```

I want to select all the rows from table called CALLFORWARDING where SRFID = MasterCode. But there are multiple SRFIDs which are saved in a table called SRFTABLE. How to loop through all the distinct SRFIDs in SRFTABLE to fetch all the matching records from CALLFORWARDING TABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work?

```
Select * From callforwarding 
Where Mastercode in (select distinct(SRFID) from SRFTABLE order by SRFID)
```

Comment: Yes working as i wanted it to be. But data is more dispersed now. Can i sort all the data using SRFID? My SRFID is like SRF/0515/008, SRF/0515/001, SRF/0516/001 etc.

Comment: @waleedansari Now is it working the way you wanted ?